# WebAPI call working in Postman, returning 404 error on website

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, postman

I am having an odd  issue. When I call my webapi service from Postman, it works:
[image: Postman Call:]

but when I call it from within my browser (or from within the app), it returns a 404 error:
[image: Browser Call:]

Anyone have any idea what might be happening here?

Comment: Is this locally hosted? You didn't accidentally stop the IIS service? (which is started and stopped when starting/stopping debugging)

Comment: Yes it is locally hosted. Nope, IIS is running (and, in fact, the website is running as well).

Comment: A typical `Accept` request header from a browser looks something like this: `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8`.  Does your API reject requests that don't accept `application/json`?

Comment: In Postman, click the Preview button to compare the URI. Use Fiddler to examine the request sent from the browser to compare.

Comment: Take a look at your eventlog. I had an issue with the `*/*;q=0.8` which web api can't handle because of an invalid format or something like this (dont know the exact error message).

Comment: Sorry for the silence. I'm not sure what was going on, but I was able to get it working, more or less. Jeroen might have been right about the IIS service being stopped.